# Ruby Set: Case insensitive difference

Tags: ruby, set

How can we add a new `difference_insenitive` method to `Set` so that it ignores the case while comparing and keep the result in the original case? For instance:

The regular `Set#difference` works like this

```
=> Set[:A, :B, :C].difference(Set[:a, :B])
=> #<Set: {:A, :C}>
```

What I wanted to have is

```
=> Set[:A, :B, :C].difference_case_insensitive(Set[:a, :B])
=> #<Set: {:C}>
```

I want to keep the original `Set#difference` so that I can compare with and without ignoring the case.

Comment: What if one of the sets contains multiple entries that only differ in case? `Set[:foo, :Foo, :FOO, :foO]` is a perfectly valid set with 4 distinct entries. But according to your definition, they should be treated like one. Maybe you actually want / need a case-insensitive `Set` class.

Comment: Stefan, yes since I need a case-insensitive comparison, in my case `[:foo, :Foo, :FOO, :foO]` would be considered the same.

Answer (score 4):

### Re-Open the Set Class

You can create a little syntactic sugar by reopening the Set class and adding a couple of utility methods. The trick is really in handling the edge cases, such as objects that don't respond to #downcase (e.g. Integer, Float, or NilClass). For example, using Ruby 2.7.1:

```
class Set
  def difference! other_set
    s1 = downcase self
    s2 = downcase other_set
    s1 - s2
  end

  protected

  def downcase set
    set.map { _1.respond_to?(:downcase) ? _1.downcase : _1 }
  end
end
```

The following examples use the modified Set class to illustrate some typical results:

```
Set[:A, :B, :C].difference! Set[:a, :B]
#=> [:c]

Set[:A, :B, :C, 1, nil].difference! Set[:a, :B]
#=> [:c, 1, nil]

Set[:A, :b, :c, 1, nil, 'foo'].difference! Set[:a, :B, "FOO"]
#=> [:c, 1, nil]
```

If you prefer to use #upcase instead so the set difference returns `:C` instead of `:c`, go right ahead. Likewise, if you'd really rather use `Set#difference_insensitive` instead of `Set#difference!` you certainly can. I like using a bang method for this use case better, but [naming things is the *other* hard thing](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/19836) in computer science.

### Caveats

Comparisons can be tricky. Whether you upcase or downcase, the results are potentially half-wrong because uppercase and lowercase characters are different objects. Since `:A` and `:a` are two different labels with two different character cases, which one should it return as the "different" character?

It also doesn't work as one might expect on multi-character labels or String objects when the upper- or lowercase conversion results in a lack of differences. For example, the following is correct but non-intuitive because all the values convert to `:foobar`.

```
Set[:foobar, :fooBar, :fOoBaR].difference! Set[:FOOBAR, :foobar]
#=> []
```

This may or may not be relevant to your use case. However, even if it worked, it still begs the question of which idosyncratic spelling should be returned when the character cases are compared.

Depending on your real data, you may need to dig into [Set#compare_by_identity](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-compare_by_identity), [Set#classify](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-classify), and [Comparable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Comparable.html) for various ways to define/compare your Set data in ways that may work around this problem. If you go this route, you may also need to reopen to Set class to define `<=>`, but it's not inherently obvious how you should best implement this if you don't have clear expectations about *how* you plan to compare dissimilar objects outside of the sample data you posted in your original question.

Comment: I think your first caveat would apply if we talk about case-insensitive intersection of sets, but set difference is not commutative anyway. Hence we would have to keep always what is inside `self`: The difference `Set.new([:foo, :Foo, :bar]).difference!(Set.new([:Bar]))` will of course produce a Set consisting of `:foo` and `:Foo` and this seems to comply with the requirements of the OP.

Comment: @ToddAJacobs : However, one caveat which I find missing is what happens in a mixture of Symbols and Strings, for instance if we have `Set.new([:foo, 'Foo'])` and `Set.new([:fOO])`. Your code would keep `'Foo´'`, which might or might not be the desired effect. The OP needs to be more precise in his question.

Comment: @user1934428 `Set.new([:foo, :Foo, :bar]).difference!(Set.new([:Bar]))` produces `[:foo, :foo]` while I want `[:foo, :Foo]`.

Comment: @Todd, thank you so much for the detailed answer. As you asked in the Caveats I want the characters in case that is on the left side. So for instance for ` `Set.new([:foo, :Foo, :bar]).difference!(Set.new([:Bar]))` produces `[:foo, :foo]` while I want `[:foo, :Foo]`.`

Comment: @ToddAJacobs : As Saim pointed out, you are accidentally converting the Sets into Arrays. Because you are using `map` in _downcase_, you need to place a Set constructor into this function.

Comment: @Todd I mostly need it for string, integer, and float comparisons.

Comment: @ToddAJacobs base on your answer how about this? `class Set
  def difference!(other_set)
    other_set_downcased = other_set.map {|m| try_downcase(m) }.to_set
    reject{|m| other_set_downcased.include?(try_downcase(m))}
  end

  protected

  def try_downcase(m)
   [String, Symbol].include?(m.class) ? m.to_s.downcase : m
  end
end`

Comment: What effectively it's doing is converting the other_set to downcase (strings and symbols only) and rejecting all both-side-downcased matching members.